# replace all with java matcher

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to add hyperlink on stock information using JAVA matcher.

For example, this string will be changed

`How do you think about Samsung and LG? I think Samsung is good.`

to

`How do you think about <a href="" kospi-code="005930">Samsung</a> and <a href="" kospi-code="003550">LG</a>? I think <a href="" kospi-code="005930">Samsung</a> is good.`

But, result was not I expected. :(
It was only added 005930.

Here is output.

`How do you think about <a href="" kospi-code="005930">Samsung</a> and <a href="" kospi-code="005930">LG</a>? I think <a href="" kospi-code="005930">Samsung</a> is good.`

Here is my code snippets.
What did I wrong?

```
String multipleStocks = "How do you think about Samsung and LG? I think Samsung is good.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Hansum|LG|Samsung");
Matcher m = p.matcher(multipleStocks);

HashMap<String, String> stocks = new HashMap<String, String>();

stocks.put("Hansum", "020000");
stocks.put("Samsung", "005930");
stocks.put("LG", "003550");
String ts = null;

while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
    ts = m.replaceAll("<a "+stocks.get(m.group(0))+">$0</a>"); 
}
System.out.println(ts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this to other communitiy and someone gave me an answer.

I used `Matcher.replaceAll` but what had needed to me was `Matcher.appendReplacement`.

```
    while(m.find()){
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "<a "+stocks.get(m.group(0))+">$0</a>");
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
```

Comment: @Gab It needs 2 days for accept own answer. Thank you Gab.

Answer (score 2):

try this in place of your loop.

```
for (String key : stocks.keySet()) {
    multipleStocks=multipleStocks.replaceAll(key, "<a "+stocks.get(key)+">$0</a>");
}

System.out.println(multipleStocks);
```

Comment: Appricate your answer. I found another solution but your's works well. Thank you @rht.

Comment: Oh, I found a problem that is existing similar keys in `stocks`. For instance, if `LG Elotronics` is exists in stocks, then link will be `<a href="" kospi-code="005930"><a href="" kospi-code="066570">LG</a> Eloctronics</a>`

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll() is

Replaces every subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern with the given replacement string.

the first loop m.find() is matcher Samsung , but replaceAll() is matcher Samsung and LG .

the second loop m.find() will return false,because m is changed.

you can annotation this code // ts = m.replaceAll("");

and execute , will print Samsung LG Samsung

Comment: Thank you but I want to attach html tag to such as Samsung and LG, not want to watch what has printed out.